# Migrating from RabbitMQ to Webshpere MQ

Tags: rabbitmq, ibm-mq, spring-jms, spring-amqp

We have been doing some POCs with RabbitMQ. However there is some debate going on if we need to move away from RabbitMQ to Webshpere MQ.

So ignoring the licensing factors purely from a technical standpoint can some one explain how this will work.

1. What is the performance for Webshpere MQ vs Rabbit MQ.
2. What are the integration aspects of Webshpere MQ with Spring framework.
3. Internally Websphere MQ i understand uses MQI, so how does this compare with AMQP.

Appreciate any pointers on the above questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't/won't speak to performance, but it shouldn't be too hard for simple PTP and Pub/Sub use cases.

RabbitMQ is much more flexible than JMS due to its many exchange types and decoupling of publishers and subscribers due to the rich exchange/binding mechanisms.

You can get some of that functionality using message selectors on the consumer side.

Spring (main framework) provides a JMS abstraction in the spring-jms jar - see [the Spring Framework documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html).